# Rotate imageview stuck

Tags: android, imageview, rotateanimation

I want to create a simple image which rotates 20 degrees (like clock) and 20 degrees back. I have this simple layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/witewall_3">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/pet"
        android:src="@drawable/animal"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and this activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ImageView image=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pet);

        RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0f, 0f, RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

        anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        anim.setDuration(700);

        image.startAnimation(anim);
    }
}
```

what am I doing wrong and my image is not rotating?
i've tried a lot of tutorials and nothink worked :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are rotating from 0 to 0 degrees. The first parameter is the from degrees and the second parameter of the RotationAnimation class is the ending point degrees.

```
RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0f, 20f, RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
```

If you want to continue to rotate by twenty you also need to provide the first parameter which is the degrees from which it will animate.

```
RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(20f, 40f, RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(40f, 60f, RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set degree from 0 to 360 when you define RatateAnimation()

RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(0, 360);
rotateAnimation.setDuration(5000);
rotateAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
rotateAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.INFINITE);
image.setAnimation(rotateAnimation);
```

Comment: While this code-only answer may solve the problem at hand, more explanation is necessary to help future users of the site understand how to apply this solution to their situation.  Please consider adding to your answer.